# Flex Spark: How to add a Cancel button on the TabBar Button?

Tags: apache-flex, button, flex4, tabs

I'm trying to add a cancel icon to my TabBarButtons in Flex 4.0 (Spark), and I've gotten close, but now I'm stuck on getting the icon to be "clickable"

I have seen other approaches, like FlexWiz Blog (http://flexwiz.amosl.com/flex/spark-tabs-with-close-button/), but was hoping to figure out something cleaner.

Using the similar approach found in the [Tour de Flex sample on Tabbed Navigation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/web/#sampleId=31160;docIndex=0;illustIndex=1), here is what I have in my skin so far:

```
<s:HGroup top="5" right="5" left="5" verticalAlign="middle">        
        <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
                 textAlign="left"
                 maxDisplayedLines="1"
                 top="10"
                 width="100%">
        </s:Label>      

        <s:Graphic x="16" y="16" 
                   buttonMode="true" 
                   mouseEnabledWhereTransparent="false" 
                   useHandCursor="true"  
                   click="closeEmployeeButtonClicked()"
                   color="0x00FF00">
            <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('assets/images/icons/close.png')"                            
                           height="16" width="16" fillMode="scale"/>
        </s:Graphic>
</s:HGroup>
```

The icon appears in the tab, however, I can't click it.  I also tried a button and it's almost like the parent button container does not allow the child to be clickable.  I did play with some parent properties (like super.mouseChildren), but couldn't get it to work.

Any thoughts!

Kind regards,
=Dave

Comment: Does closeEmployeeButtonClicked() ever get called?

Comment: Good question - It is not being called. When the image is clicked, the entire tab button depresses.  So, it's almost like anything inside the boundaries of the button can't be "clickable". 

I also tried to remove all the shading and borders in the Button skin, but had no success getting the graphic area to see the click. 

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Instead of the Graphic/Bitmap image, I also tried a button with a custom skin that renders an icon: <s:Button styleName="closetab" skinClass="skins.CustomImageButtonSkin" label="Close" click="closeEmployeeButtonClicked()"/> But it behaved the same... taking these two close buttons outside of the button parent container works fine

Answer (score 1):

I see that the post is pretty old, but I just came along the same issue.
In order for button to be clickable, you need to enable mouseChildren at a TabBarButtonSkin. You can do it as follows:

```
override protected function commitProperties():void
{
    super.commitProperties();
    hostComponent.mouseChildren = true;
}
```

Now your button should be clickable. At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's already done in flexlib library. You can find some examples here:

http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/SuperTabNavigator_Sample.swf

and here is its project home page:

http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/

Comment: Good idea, but the SuperTabNavigator is based on mx (Flex 3) components.  The question is specific to Flex 4 spark components and skins.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Sorry for that. I was using this lib in my Flex 3 project and noticed that there was also Flex 4 version, so I thought that they rewrote it all for Flex 4. Oh naive me ;) Anyway Dave can still use that as an example of how he can solve some problems that may come out.

Comment: Yes, good idea, thank you!  I'll take a look at how SuperTabNavigator was built.  I am also trying to stay away from 3rd party components, to see if it can be done just using the skin in Flex 4.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Flex 4 based tab control that appears to be very well done, full source included:

http://saturnboy.com/2010/08/terrifictabbar-custom-component/